# standard value of iPhone tableview row height

Tags: iphone, uitableview, height, row, standards

what is the standard value of iPhone tableview row height? every where I look it says it will be set to standard value what is this value in points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look in interface builder.  44 px
Drop a table in and look on the dimensions tab.